# How to assign 40 projects into a project category in JIRA?

Tags: jira

I can assign a project to a project category by Administration -> Projects -> Select a project -> Select a project category. But I have to do this multiple times for 40 projects.

Is there any way to do this with less number of clicking?

Comment: The Hundred Tab problem, vote for https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-24961

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple answer: **You can't through the interface.** 
There may be some way through the REST API, but it ain't worth it for only 40 projects. 
40 project are not so many after all and you can minimize the clicking if you open all the projects that you're going to edit in separate tabs.

Comment: Currently (5.1), the REST API can't even be used to fetch the category of a project.